# Iterate through list to update particular items in the list

Tags: list

How can I update the values in a list for the indices that are equal to everyone in the selected group agents?:

```
persons-own [
   grouped        
   flockmates
]

to create-trustConnection
  set nrPersons count persons 
  set vector []
  repeat nrPersons [set vector 0.4 vector]
end

to updateVector   
  let alonePersons (count persons with [grouped = false])
  set flockmates n-of (random alonePersons) persons 
  ask flockmates [
    foreach vector [ i ->
      set item i vector 0.6
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: As it has already been suggested to you in your other question, you should provide a [mre]: the smalles amount of code that is necessary to reproduce the type of problem you're having, and such that we can just copy&paste it to be able to reproduce the problem on our side without the need of adding or changing or even understanding anything of it beforehand. Note that it should be both reproducible AND minimal: at the moment, your question contains a huge deal of noise with many things and much information that are not the heart of the problem. Doing so will surely help you get help

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace-item` reporter to update an item in a list.

```
Let this [ 1 2 3 4 ]
Let new-list replace-item 3 this “a”
Print new-list
```

Note that this does not affect the original list: it reports a new list with the specified item replaced with the given value.

Changing an item in a list of lists of similar.. but again, the entire list
Of lists is created anew.

### But maybe use links?

In the case of using a list for a turtle to track its relationship with other turtles, or of groups, `links` are useful, and simplify managing those relationships, and enable things that are very difficult with lists.

LINKS are just another kind of agent, specifically for recording a relationship between two turtles. They have a pair of built-in variables, `end1` and `end2` that refer to those two turtles. The `-own` variables of the link can be used to record properties of the relationship. Like “anniversary” or “affinity” or whatever! Links can be directional, so the “intimacy” value can be different depending on the “direction” of the relationship.

```
Directed-link-breed [ relationships relationship]
Relationships-own [ intimacy ]

to setup-all-relationships
  Ask protestors
  [ setup-relationship ]
End

To setup-relationship
  ;; link with everyone else 
  Create-relationships-to other protestor
  [ set intimacy .5 ]
End
```

The relationship between two turtles can be obtained in several ways.

(Link (this turtle) (that turtle))

Refers to the link from this turtle to that turtle.

Out-Link-neighbors is used to get the set of all turtles linked to from this turtle.

You can also use turtles to represent groups, and links to record membership in that group.

In that case, the members of the group are `link-neighbors` of the group.

While perhaps not a feature of your model, this opens up the possibility of multiple groups and of agents being members of more than one group, or of tracking things like former members.

Comment: @TurtleZero's code works for me after I make the changes you note.  I suggest that you post your code as a separate question so that we can take a look at it.  It's hard to diagnose in a vacuum!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete, minimal reproducible example of what I think you are looking for.  Note that one can just paste it into NetLogo and it compiles and runs.  I've made some assumptions here - in particular that `intimacy` is a `protesters-own` variable, which it was not in the code you provided, but which your textual description seemed to indicate.  Again, using who numbers is not a good idea, but that is a different question and answer.  If I have time tomorrow, I might be able to provide you with an example of how one might use agentsets, but if intimacy values can vary from agent-pair to agent-pair, then links is really the way to go.

```
breed [protesters protester]
globals [numberOfProtesters intimacyVector]

protesters-own [
  intimacy
  partOfGroup         ;initially set to false for all agents
  myNRelatedProtesters
]

to setup 
  clear-all
  create-protesters 10
  create-intimacyRelationship
  reset-ticks
end

to create-intimacyRelationship
  ask protesters [
    set numberOfProtesters count protesters 
    set intimacy []
    repeat numberOfProtesters [set intimacy lput 0.2 intimacy] 
    set partOfGroup false
  ]
end

to updateIntimacy 
  let nrUngroupedProtesters (count protesters with [partOfGroup = false])
  let NRelatedProtesters n-of (random nrUngroupedProtesters) protesters 
  ask NRelatedProtesters [
    foreach ([who] of NRelatedProtesters) [ i -> set intimacy replace-item i intimacy 0.8 ]
    set partOfGroup true
  ]
  ask NRelatedProtesters [ show intimacy ]
end

to go
  let ProportionProtestersInSubgroup (count protesters with [partOfGroup = true])/ numberOfProtesters  
  ifelse ((count protesters with [partOfGroup = false])/ 
    numberOfProtesters) > ProportionProtestersInSubgroup 
  [ 
    updateIntimacy
  ]
  [
    stop
  ]
  tick  
end
```

Hope this gets you started.